# Delete recursively files in a folder and in child folder

Tags: bash, shell

I want to delete all files contained in a folder and his subfolder recursively without deleteing folders.

For example I have this structure :

```
MainFolder
│   Somefile6
│   Somefile7
│ 
└───child1
│   |   Somefile
│   |   Somefile2
│   │   
│   └───child2  
│       │   Somefile3
│       │   Somefile4
│       │
│       └───child3
│           │   Somefile5
```

After running a bash script (what I tried) :

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob dotglob # Include hidden file
dir=(/root/some/path/*)
if [ ${#dir[@]} -gt 0 ]; then
    for file in "$dir"
    do
        echo "Doing some custom action before deleting..."
        echo "Deleting $file"
        rm "$file"
        sleep 1
    done
else
    echo "The folder is empty";
fi
```

What I expect to obtain

```
MainFolder
│ 
└───child1
│   │   
│   └───child2  
│       │
│       └───child3
│           │
```

---

Problem:

It's just deleting the files `Somefile6` and `Somefile7`

Comment: Because that's what you told it to do.  `for file in "$dir"`.

Comment: How can I parse all folders? @Robert the duplicate answer you marked doesn't answer my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `find` to look for all files and let it delete those:

```sh
find -type f -delete
```

- `-type f`: tells `find` to only yield files
- `-delete`: tells `find`
  to delete all the found items

If you don't want to delete the files you can use `-exec` and do what ever you want with the files `find` yields.

Comment: I know but I need to use it in a recursive way, because I'm going to do some action before deleting

Comment: If you want to do something else just use `-exec` instead of `-delete`. I've updated the post.

Comment: Can I use condition in the exec ?

Comment: If the code you want to execute is more complex - just pass a script.

Comment: How can I execute a custom function with `-exec` ?

Comment: `export -f somefunc; find . -exec bash -c 'somefunc "$0"' {} \`
Here it'll execute `somefunc` which you need to define in our script.